# How to compare 24 hours record against another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
TableA
MemberID    property    LoginTime
1           A           2016-09-12 1300        
1           A           2016-09-12 1400        
1           B           2016-09-13 1300        

TableB
MemberID    profit    property        LoginTime
1           100       A               2016-09-14 1400
1           -80       B               2016-09-14 1200
1           200       A               2016-09-14 1300
1           300       B               2016-09-14 1400
3           800       A               2014-09-14 1400
```

---

```
Expected Result
ResultTable
MemberID    profit      property        LoginTime
1           200         A               2016-09-14 1pm
1           300         B               2016-09-14 2pm
3           800         A               2014-09-14 2pm
```

How to write a query to fulfill the below criteria:

- Member record in TableB is not in TableA
- Member record in particular property that is in TableB, the logintime is greater than 24 hours as compare to TableA against the same property
- TableB act as a master table.

Comment: can you please share desired output?

Comment: Datediff is what you need, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: @maulikkansara : The desired output was there under "Expected Result" section

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select * 
from tableB b
where not exists (
      select 1
      from tableA a
      where a.MemberID = b.MemberID and a.Property = b.Property
          and b.LoginTime between a.LoginTime and dateadd(hh,24, a.LoginTime) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This has the exact same result set as in the question :

```
declare @TableA table (MemberID int, property char(1), LoginTime datetime)
declare @TableB table (MemberID int, profit int, property char(1), LoginTime datetime)

insert into @TableA values (1, 'A', '20160913 12:00')
insert into @TableA values (1, 'B', '20160913 13:00')

insert into @TableB values (1, 100, 'A', '20160914 11:00')
insert into @TableB values (1, -80, 'B', '20160914 12:00')
insert into @TableB values (1, 200, 'A', '20160914 13:00')
insert into @TableB values (1, 300, 'B', '20160914 14:00')
insert into @TableB values (3, 800, 'A', '20160914 14:00')

select B.*
from   @TableB B
  left outer join @TableA A on B.MemberID = A.MemberID
                           and B.Property = A.Property
where DATEDIFF(hh, isnull(A.LoginTime, '19000101'), B.LoginTime) >= 24
```

**EDIT : the Op has provided new sample data so I had to adjust my query :**

```
declare @TableA table (MemberID int, property char(1), LoginTime datetime)
declare @TableB table (MemberID int, profit int, property char(1), LoginTime datetime)

insert into @TableA values (1, 'A', '20160912 13:00')
insert into @TableA values (1, 'A', '20160912 14:00')
insert into @TableA values (1, 'B', '20160913 13:00')

insert into @TableB values (1, 100, 'A', '20160914 14:00')
insert into @TableB values (1, -80, 'B', '20160914 12:00')
insert into @TableB values (1, 200, 'A', '20160914 13:00')
insert into @TableB values (1, 300, 'B', '20160914 14:00')
insert into @TableB values (3, 800, 'A', '20160914 14:00')

select B.MemberID, B.profit, B.property, B.LoginTime
from   @TableB B
  left outer join @TableA A on B.MemberID = A.MemberID
                           and B.Property = A.Property
where DATEDIFF(hh, isnull(A.LoginTime, '19000101'), B.LoginTime) > 24
group by B.MemberID, B.profit, B.property, B.LoginTime
```

As I understand his criteria the desired output should be this however :

Expected Result
ResultTable

```
MemberID    profit      property        LoginTime
1           100         A               2016-09-14 2pm
1           200         A               2016-09-14 1pm
1           300         B               2016-09-14 2pm
3           800         A               2014-09-14 2pm
```

Comment: your query doesn't seems to check against property field?

Comment: I think Mr.SuicideSheep means that Row of TableB is not in TableA. Therefor the Join needs to be on MemberID, property as well as LoginTime.. At least that's waht the output is showing...

Comment: I edited my answer it now includes the property in the join. I dont think I can include the LoginTime in the join because than I cannot check on different by 24 hours anymore

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep I edited my answer and when I run in I get the exact same result set as your desired result from your question.

Comment: @GuidoG: Your suggested answer almost got what I want. However kindly have a look at my updated question whereby I've added another record in TableA, your answer will not achieve the resultTable due to the left join am I right?

Comment: Yes with these sample data my resultset is now different. I tested the answer from Serg and it now also has a different result where this was still correct with your first sample data.

Comment: But I dont think it is because of the left join. I will analize this later

Comment: your criteria : Member record in TableB is not in TableA. How must I read this ? in your desired output records in B that are not in A are not in the desired output but this criteria said they should be. Can you elaborate more on how you get to your desired resultset ?

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep I edited my answer. As I read your criteria there should be one record more in your outcome. Can you please elaborate why this extra record should not be in your desired outcome ?

Comment: @GuidoG: That was referring to the data in column "MemberID". As you can see in TableB, there is a record with memberID = 3 but there is none in TableA, hence it appear in ResultTable

Comment: That is what the left join does. But why is the first record in tableB not in your desired output ?

Comment: This record also shows up in the answer from Serge so I guess he saw it the same as I did

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    B.*
from
    TableB B
left join
    TableA A        on (B.MemberID = A.MemberID and B.Property = A.Property)
left join
    TableA A1       on (B.MemberID = A1.MemberID and B.Property = A1.Property and B.logintime > dateadd(hh, 24, A1.loginTime))
where
    A.MemberID is null or A1.MemberID is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Query is in MSSQL format.

```
select  b.* from @TableB B 
left join @TableA A 
on b.MemberID=a.MemberID and b.property=a.property
where datediff(hour,a.logintime,b.logintime)>=24 
or a.MemberID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl, should be simple enough with a LEFT JOIN then just ensure a field in the joined tabled is NULL.

In a local test I've got the same result set as specified in the questions

```
select * 
from @tableB b
LEFT JOIN @tableA as a on a.MemberId = b.MemberId
    and a.Property = b.Property
    and b.LoginTime between a.LoginTime and dateadd(hh,24, a.LoginTime)
where a.MemberId IS NULL
```